# Selecting specific value in Enum

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I'm new in using MVC4 and I just want to ask on how to select a specific number of value in a enumerable option or add validation. What I am trying to achieve is how can I show the first 2 status on my Dropdown when i logged-in the a different user. here's my code:

```
    public enum DeliveryPermitStatus
    {

        Arrived = 1,
        Approved = 2,
        Cancelled = 3,
        Completed = 4,
        Submitted = 5
    }
```

I just want to select the first 2 option in enum depending on the logged user I tried using Linq and validation in Html view but to no afford I cant keep up with a solution. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to pull data from a database? What? Question is unclear.

Comment: Could you try to add more context on what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

for select one option in `enum` you can do it:

```
int ApprovedCode = System.Convert.ToInt32(DeliveryPermitStatus.Approved);
```

and use `ApprovedCode` to initialize your control

Comment: What if i just want to show Arrived and Approved in my Dropdown ?

Comment: @EnriqueGil then you just have your dropdown have the options with the values of `int ApprovedCode = System.Convert.ToInt32(DeliveryPermitStatus.Approved);` and `int ArrivedCode = System.Convert.ToInt32(DeliveryPermitStatus.Arrived);`